# How do I get rid of mysterious stuff displayed on my cellular's screen?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

There is tiny writing listing currently running systems and a red frame around my screen and a white dot wherever I touch the screen and a thin white and red line blocking my notification bar with writing that looks like stock market listings.  How do I get rid of all these items?

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Just turn it off in *Settings->Development*. This sounds as if you turned on the process overlay and some other feedback options there.

Answer (score 3):

You most likely switched on several feedback settings in *Settings→Developer Options*:

[image: Developer Options]
<sup>Developer Options (Source: [AndroidAdvices.Com](http://androidadvices.com/touchscreen-on-android-phone/))</sup>

In these screenshots the reason for the "white dot" wherever you touch the screen is already marked. Additionally, you probably have enabled "Show CPU usage" as well (right screenshot, lower third). Just turn everything off here which you don't know what it's for; by default, nothing is checked in this menu.

Answer (score -1):

Settings → Developer options → *Uncheck* Show layout boundaries.